# Does npm install package twice?

Tags: node.js, npm

I run `npm install` to install my dependencies.

At the first time, some package install failed.

I ran `npm install` again.

Will `npm` reinstall every dependency again or just the package not be installed?

Comment: Why not just test this? The answer is it checks for updates and only installs what is missing or needs to be / can be updated.

Comment: @Stian At first time, I know some packages has been installed in `node_modules` directory. But at second time, will `npm` replace the packages which existed?

Comment: no, only if it needs to.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Running `npm install` apart from the first time installs only the missing packages and those that need update.

As per stian's input, refer [docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm](http://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install` after the first time only installs missing packages or updates existing ones.