# Is npm install downloads packages each time?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm working on an app that have `550 MB` of `node_modules`

my question in short.

Is `npm i` command going to download this bunch of data each time i execute it ?

Comment: Not unless you delete the content of node_modules and your local cache before running it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe direct and fast answer Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

All modules will not be reinstalled every time unless it needs an update/if the module is not available.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355129/5409923